# Enabling SVN tracking in a git clone of a git-svn clone that didn't start at revision 1?

Tags: git-svn

Suppose I have a `git svn clone` that I created like this:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ git svn clone -s -r 100:HEAD http://svn.example.com/project
```

and then I `git clone` it like this:

```
$ cd ..
$ git clone foo bar
$ cd bar
```

So now `bar` has `foo` as its origin.

How do I make `bar` track the original SVN server? The `git-svn` man page provides an example of the case where the original `git svn clone` includes the full revision history, but this doesn't seem to cover the case that the original `git svn clone` doesn't start from `r1`. When I try the various things I see described, what `git svn fetch` does is always start a disconnected history starting at `r1`.

Comment: I think my problem was that I didn't actually have standard layout. I believe it worked once I set my trunk, branches, and tags explicitly.